# "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread" when playing a full screen video from a webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, autolayout

I have a `webview` in a `collectionview cell` that holds an **embedded** youtube video. Whenever I tap the youtube video, it goes full screen. This is what I want it do to, but the console is spitting out the following error:

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
```

I've dealt with this error several times before, and normally I'd just wrap the relevant code with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){  *code*  }
```

However, this issue seems to be triggered by the action generated by the `webview` itself. I'm not sure how to fix this. Is there any way for me to intercept the `webview action` and **re-route** it to the `main thread`?

EDIT 1/3 - I built a very basic project to replicate the issue. It consists of a uicollectionviewcontroller with one cell type. The cell code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class videoCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIWebView!
    var video : String? {
        didSet {
            let components = video!.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
            let videoID = components[1]
            let playerLink = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID
            let playerURL = NSURL(string: playerLink)
            print("loading...")
            self.videoView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: playerURL!))
        }
    }
}
```

My code in cellForItemAtIndexPath is as follows:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! videoCellCollectionViewCell
    let video = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGRC1DV7b78"
    cell.video = video
    return cell
}
```

I am getting the same issue with this bare bones code.

Comment: Hello please refer to an answer i wrote here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701447/quicktime-player-ios-9-on-uiwebview-giving-warning-after-play-is-pressed/35725027#35725027